# How to use a Javascript code into Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

Im trying to make a scrollable table both horizontal and vertical by using a last example (Datatable horizontal and vertical scroll) by https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/scroll/

under src/components/ScrollExample.js, I copied and pasted html codes.
under src/styles/components/_scroll.scss, I also copied and pasted css codes from an example.  The table came out exactly the same as the once in the example.

But here is im stuck on. Now I have all the layout is fixed but i cannot get the javascript going.

I tied to write the below code under public/index.html but i get and error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dtHorizontalVerticalExample').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  "scrollY": 200,
  });
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
  });
```

how do I fix this error? I appreciate all your comments.

Comment: Looks like jQuery isn't loaded correctly.

Comment: probably not the best way to approach this issue. try to find something in react that solves this table problem. 
or you can use the dirty way and just put this in a script tag in the component you want to use it in (if you have global jQuery loaded). If you use a script tag then you are using 2 libs to make a ui solution (react and jQuery) and thats bad for maintainability + bundle size + consistency.

Comment: You can use React Material or Ant Design Md-bootstrap  is not free,Only Pro member are used.

Comment: You're using 2 libraries here 1. jQuery and 2. jQuery DataTables, so my guess is you must install both of them first then import them and then your code would work. ex: `npm i jquery` then `import $ from 'jquery'` , check on npmjs.com for Datatable library

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't included JQuery in your html file.

You can add JQuery to the html by putting it in the Head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using jQuery and not vanilla javascript.
jQuery is a library from javascript Read more about it at: [Jquery - Download](https://jquery.com/download/) and here: [W3schools - jQuery Get Started](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)
I also recommend that you use a CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```